# how can I use the linkedin search feature in my app

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to use the linkedin search feature to look for candidates within only the linkedin population, is there any way to do that through there API?

Comment: the search would be embedded in a separate application

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn does not currently provide access to any search-related APIs to the public.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, do you know if you can access this through one of their paid features, such as talent solutions?